# Small caps (missing) and font choice with fontspec

Tags: fonts, fontspec, small-caps, times, octavo

The `octavo` package is supposed to print headings in small caps but I'm probably using a font that does not allow small caps? Or what am I doing wrong because even in the text I cannot set small caps. The command `\textsc{word}` does nothing. My document is in Italian (main language) and Hebrew. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[crown]{octavo}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=40pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[italian]{varioref}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\usepackage{lipsum}  

\usepackage{relsize,etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{relsize,etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\smaller}% Step font down one size relative to current font.

\usepackage{quoting}
\quotingsetup{font=small}

\usepackage{imakeidx}\makeindex[name=concetti,title=Indice dei concetti,columns=3]
\makeindex[name=tecniche,title=Indice delle techniche,columns=3]

\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
\graphicspath{/Users/haimbook/Desktop/}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}

\Xlemmafont{\bfseries}
\Xnotefontsize[A]{\scriptsize}

\fnpos{critical-familiar}
\Xbeforenotes[A]{1.8em}
\beforenotesX[A]{1.8em}
\beforenotesX[B]{1.8em}
\Xafterrule[A]{7pt}
\afterruleX[A]{7pt}
\afterruleX[B]{7pt}


\firstlinenum{100000}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{New Peninim MT}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad3, doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false]{biblatex}

\bibliography{Midrash.bib}


\begin{document}



%\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteA}{\arabic{footnoteA}}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteB}{\alph{footnoteB}}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%STARTHERE%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-4]


\part{Bibliografia}
\printbibliography[heading=none]




%\indexprologue{\small Questo indice contiene nomi di persone famose.}
\printindex[concetti]
\printindex[tecniche]

 \tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please extend your code. As [has been](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/629632) [pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/629632), it is impossible to diagnose your issue unless you give a **small** but complete, **compilable** example (MWE). You can create a short new .tex file, compile it, and if the problem persists, copy the code here. Without this small effort on your part, nobody can really help you!

Comment: Ok you are right! Please see how I did correct the question and tried to post a MWE. I left all of my preamble. Should I clean up the non font-related  parts? I left all of it in doubt something might matter... Thanks!

Comment: PS: I also have Greek in my text, with now prints appropriately. I had made some tinkering with my font commands in the preamble obtaining small caps, but for some reasons I ended up loosing the Greek...

Comment: Thanks for editing the example! Yes, as a general rule it's always better to keep it short and remove the unrelated parts. Doing this is part of the solution btw: as you remove more and more bits, you will probably get a hunch of which line/pkg/option is causing the trouble, and which ones are innocent. @"in doubt something might matter": generally, if you take it away and the problem persists, it didn't matter to the problem. This reduces the "noise" and leads to minimal examples. Now for the actual problem: see my answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for editing the example.
Your hunch was correct, there seems to be a problem with the font that I could replicate (and is actually quite common).

(Caveat: "missing font" warnings are system-dependent, they can vary from user to user, if they have different fonts installed. So they're not always replicable when sharing code, as in a MWE!)

Older versions of Times New Roman [are known](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470414/times-new-roman-and-small-caps) to lack the small capitals feature. In fact, the minimal example

```
\documentclass[crown]{octavo}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
Hello {\scshape world} and \textsc{goodbye}.
\end{document}
```

gives the warning (in the .log) `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape` TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/sc' undefined (Font) using `TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n' instead on input line 8.` and prints the text accordingly. You might have an old implementation of the font too.

Unfortunately, Times New Roman is a proprietary font. But the clone font developed for TeX, [TeX Gyre Termes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex-gyre-termes), is free and provides all text styles. [Install it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470458) via tlmgr or as you would any font in your specific system.

Then you can either set it as your main font entirely

```
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
```

or [selectively for small capitals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187423), keeping Times for all other uses:

```
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[
  SmallCapsFont={TeX Gyre Termes},
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
]
```

(Note that the issue occurs independent of the document class – in your case, octavo.)

Comment: Thanks this is clear! Since the problem seems to be the font, I tried some other ways to change it and found that if I comment the `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` but use instead `\usepackage{ebgaramond}` this also solves the issue. But only if I use ebgaramond, as other fonts like Palatino give me other issues. So my question is: 1) What is the difference in using one or the other of the above in the preamble; 2) Is there somewhere a handy resource to know what font has what characteristic?

Comment: PS: Should I open another thread instead?

Comment: The first thing to do would be to search the site. Chances are there's already a solution out there. If this doesn't help, you should open a new question. And maybe this can help in the meantime? https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/